# Pass a global variable to the $(document).ready function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site that has particular alphanumeric ID for every song, say like `57bfab618de4191` In the jQuery player the MP3 song has to be assigned via link.

The jplayer function is this:

```
     $(document).ready(function (){
   function playAudio(val) {newVal=val}    

        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function (event) {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
    mp3:"http://website.com/dlb.php?file="+newVal                       });
            },
            swfPath: "js",
            supplied: "mp3",
            wmode: "window"
        });
    });
```

I want to play different song present in the list for user so I passed a ID of song via button `onClick` like this

```
  onClick="playAudio(<?php echo "'".$songid. "'"; ?>)"
```

Where song ID is the iD of the song specified in database, like `57bfab618de4191`

This way I can pass the value, but I am not able to transfer the parameter of playAudio function to the `document.ready` function.

Comment: Echo the ID into a data attribute and get it with jQuery inside the function, and get rid of that inline click handler.

Comment: @adeneo how,, actually, can you describe? I don't want page to be refreshed and also , the id is present at the play button of the song and there is list i cant assign the id globally anywhere. I have to use onClick function for specific song

Comment: I'm guessing something like [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dhdTE/)...

Comment: try `mp3:"http://website.com/dlb.php?file="+newVal+".mp3"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var val = 'whateveer'

function playAudio(nval) {
    var val = nval;
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function(event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "http://website.com/dlb.php?file=" + val
            });
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
}
```

no need for `$(document).ready`

---

if you need to change songs:

```
var val = '12345'; // your first song
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function(event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "http://website.com/dlb.php?file=" + val
            });
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
});

function playAudio(nval) {
    var val = nval;
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        "setMedia", {
            mp3: "http://website.com/dlb.php?file=" + val
        }
    });
    // --- OR ---
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").changeAndPlay("http://website.com/dlb.php?file=" + val);
}
```

More info:

- [Changing songs on jPlayer by clicking a link, hosted on Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206608/changing-songs-on-jplayer-by-clicking-a-link-hosted-on-amazon-s3)
- http://www.jplayer.org/0.2.1/developer-guide/#jPlayer-change

Comment: thanks buddy, it really helped, but want to ask one thing it doesn't overwrite the value of val when another button is clicked.

Comment: `val` is the parameter to the function, not a global variable. Each button should have a different argument value inserted by PHP.

Comment: Please check my code, you might want to destroy the current instance of jPlayer before creating a new one.

Comment: @barmar each button has already specific button inserted by php for different song, Still not working, i think that might be the problem with player.

Comment: @AbhishekGahlo i edited my answer, please try it :) and jPlayer has very nice docs why wont' you use it? :)

Comment: @peterSzymkowski thanks buddy,, the code your provided is working, and i will add changeAndPlay function :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to play with variable scoping.

```
var newVal = 'default_song_to_play_if_any';

function playAudio(val){
    newVal = val;
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("destroy");
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
       ready: function (event) {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
             mp3:"http://website.com/dlb.php?file="+newVal
          });
       },
       swfPath: "js",
       supplied: "mp3",
       wmode: "window"
   });
}

//use this ready function only if you want to play a default song on load
$(document).ready(function(){
    playAudio(newVal); 
});
```

Comment: Nested functions are fine in JavaScript.

Comment: @ShutterBug the code is good still it doesn't ful-fill my requirement as every user may have different song. I can't provide default value of song.

Comment: @steveax You are wrong: [#1](http://jsfiddle.net/wkVcJ/) [#2](http://jsfiddle.net/wkVcJ/1/)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski well this answer states: "You can not decalre a function inside document.ready because document.ready itself is a function." the examples you show are demonstrating variable scope in JavaScript. Perhaps that's what ShutterBug meant, but if so it's poorly stated.

Comment: @steveax the document.ready function is replaced with another function that can take the value, so in that way it worked thats why peterszymkowki answer is somehow correct.

Comment: Who said you can't declare function within a function?