# how to dynamically pass songs to jPlayer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, jplayer

I am working on a metro-looking asp.net application right now. It's a mp3 player where you choose artist (clicking on a tile), then album (same) and you pick a song from the list.

Now I want to pass the picked song's filename and location to jPlayer so that it replaces the actual played song. I know how to play one song specified in the players constructor but have no idea how to change it dinamically.

I don't need to stick to jPlayer, if You can recommend me any other player that can do above in easier way there is no problem :)

(English is not my main tounge, sorry for mistakes, I hope it is understandable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: url}).jPlayer("play");
```

Pulled from:
[Changing songs on jPlayer by clicking a link, hosted on Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206608/changing-songs-on-jplayer-by-clicking-a-link-hosted-on-amazon-s3)

Comment: As I said, I am a total noob in javascript, so I will need further help just to properly use Your code.

Comment: I created function:

`function songo_kan(url) {
                     $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: url }).jPlayer("play");
                 }`

And then created a link like this:

 `<a href="#" onclick='javascript:songo_kan("/Music/a.mp3"); return false'>next</a>`

But it's not working.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out and Your answer was very helpful, big thanks mate! :)

Comment: What was the solution? Did you need to put the whole url?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the code that is working for me (set id of a button to 'myPlayButton'):

```
$("#myPlayButton").click(function () {
             $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: "/Music/a.mp3"}).jPlayer("play");
         });
```

I have folder named 'Music' in a root catalog of the server.